# 'Clear' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have try to Rest button to Reset user input in TextBox in VB ASP.NET my code is here-

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">Input text:</asp:Label><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter your name here!" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label">Output text:</asp:Label><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" BackColor="#0066FF" Text="Reset" />
            <br />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And the VB code is

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        TextBox1.Attributes.Add("AutoCompleteType", "off")
        TextBox1.Focus()

        'If Not IsPostBack Then
        'TextBox1.Text = "Enter your name here!"
        'End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim MyString As String = TextBox1.Text
        'Response.Write(MyString)
        TextBox2.Text = MyString
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox1.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The error is:

> 'Clear' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'
>   'Clear' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `TextBox` does not contain a method `Clear`.
You can clear its content by assigning an empty string value to the property `Text`, as shown here below.

```
TextBox2.Text = "";
TextBox1.Text = "";
```